# unwanted changing value of an array element being address/number of element for the second array in C

Tags: c, arrays

I have problem that really confuses me a lot. I want to have a sparse matrix stored in 3 arrays and perform matrix/vector multiplication. Matrix and vectorB are red from a file. That's the background. The problem is in unwanted changing the value of an integer array element being an "argument" of the double array. Here is what I am doing:

```
int row[ELEMENTS_NO] = {0};
int col[ELEMENTS_NO] = {0};
double values[ELEMENTS_NO] = {0.0};
double vectorB[M_SIZE] = {0.0};
double res[M_SIZE]={0.0};

...reading row,col,values, from the file...

printf("\n row[0]:%d, col[0]:%d",row[0],col[0]);

for (k = 0; k < ELEMENTS_NO; k++) {
        res[row[k]] = res[row[k]] + values[k]*vectorB[col[k]];
    }

printf("\n\n\n row[0]:%d, col[0]:%d",row[0],col[0]);
```

the output of the first print is correct:

> row[0]:1, col[0]:1

while the second print gives me following output:

> row[0]:1352932126, col[0]:1

Why the value of col array changed after executing for loop? How to solve my problem and remain row and col elements unchanged?

Thank you for any useful information!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the value of row[k] and make sure it's between 0 and ELEMENTS_NO

Comment: Indeed, the range of row values was incorrect. Stupid mistake. Thank you all!

Answer (score 0):

My best guess is that one of the elements of row is negative, thus res[row[k]] would be negative.

Try running the program using valgrind, this will tell you when you have out of bounds problems for arrays.

Answer (score 0):

You are indexing res[] by a value from the row array. The first one is over 1 billion, so you are changing the (more than) billionth element of res[] which I suspect is beyond the end of the array. Then anything can happen, including overwriting other variables.